# Quickest way to display results from a table in .NET 2.0/3.5

Tags: database, gridview, datagridview

I have a database table (sql server 2008) that I want to view data for, what is the quickest way of displaying this data?

(if it could have paging that would be perfect).

Would it be a gridview or ?

query: select * from testData

Answer (score 3):

if you're using .NET 3.5 you could use ASP.NET Dynamic Data:

http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

via ADO.NET get your data into a DataSet or DataTable.

then:

```
gridview.DataSource = yourDataTable;
gridview.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

if its a web app, gridview control and use cache objects to hold data set... every time connecting to db is time consuming...

pros: performance
cons: can't handle large tables unless you have server memory to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Use LinqToSql and bind the results to a grid view.

Answer (score 0):

Gridview would be a perfect solution

you can have paging and sorting with that just by the properties AllowPaging="true" PageSize="##" AllowSorting="true" and if you want all the data and not just specific rows you can just do AutoGenerateColumns="true"